# I am Facing issues in Scanner Class in java

Tags: java

If I enter the wrong input(example , if I enter String instead of Integer) loop is not ending, it wont get input next time. Here(below) i attach the entire program. can you please help this?. Thanks in advance!!!

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * If we enter the wrong input(example , if we enter sting instead of integer) it goes unending loop
 * 
 * @author Nithish
 *
 */
public class Sample2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Enter the value");
                int obj = scanner.nextInt();
                System.out.println(obj);
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                i--;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Do you want the loop to exit on invalid input or "get the input next time"? Not clear if you want the loop to exit or if you want it to make another attempt to get the data. Any not clear what the current behavior is that is problematic.

Comment: For gosh's sake, don't modify the loop index inside the loop. Do this right and use a while loop. Myself, I'd do this with scanner.nextLine() and then parse the String via Integer.parseInt(...) catching a NumberFormatException.

Comment: scanner.hasNextInt() is even better!

Answer (score 4):

On an InputMismatchException you are doing i--, so the loop condition is modified to prevent the loop from ending without the needed input. If you read the API documentation for Scanner.nextInt() you should notice the following:

> If the translation is successful, the scanner advances past the input that matched.

This means that if the input cannot be translated to int, the scanner does not advance. So on the next invocation of nextInt() it will re-read the exact same, non-int, input and fail again. You will need to read past that non-integer token before attempting to get an int again.

Answer (score 2):

Again, don't mess with the loop index inside of the loop as this can cause problems down the road. Instead use a while loop which is much cleaner and much easier to debug 3 months from now:

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sample2 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
      boolean done = false;
      int result = 0;

      while (!done) {
         try {
            System.out.print("Enter the value: ");
            String temp = scanner.nextLine();
            result = Integer.parseInt(temp);
            done = true;
         } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Please only enter integer data");
         }
      }
      scanner.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't consuming tokens until an int is found be better? Eg while(!scanner.hasNextInt()) { scanner.next(); } int result = scanner.nextInt();

Comment: @Mark: That's a decent way as well and does avoid the Scanner's problem with the end of line token.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Enter the value");
        int obj = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println(obj);
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        i--;
        //e.printStackTrace();
        scanner.nextLine(); //you can add this here.
        //scanner.next(); you can also use this 
    }
}
```

Comment: Downvoter! Explanation please! It actually does what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: Modifying loop index inside of loop is bad form. Better to use a while loop as that is specifically what it is for. And "what the OP is trying to do" is not the right way to do this and shouldn't be encouraged.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: He was already doing that. I did not advice him to modify the loop index inside the loop. I was just focusing on the problem he was having.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: To me when I look at his code, it feels like he is trying to learn about `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

what about the below?

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while (!sc.hasNext()) {
  System.out.println("Enter the value");
   if (src.hasNextInt()) {
      i = src.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Thank you! (" + i+ ")");
   }
      else
   {
      System.out.println("Please only int");
   }
}
```